How to iterate over two properties in an object based on id?
I'm working with a JavaScript object, and when I do console.log(sessions), it outputs the following structure on console:
{
  101: { "id": 101, "nameEn": "English 1", "nameFr": "French 1" },
  102: { "id": 102, "nameEn": "English 2", "nameFr": "French 2" },
  103: { "id": 103, "nameEn": "English 3", "nameFr": "French 3" }
}

The sessions data type is an object.
I’m trying to write a function that retrieves the nameEn and nameFr values based on a given id. Here’s what I’ve tried:
// Function to fetch nameEn and nameFr based on id
const getNameById = (id) => {
  const session = sessions.find(session => session.id === id);  // Line A
  if (session) {
    return { nameEn: session.nameEn, nameFr: session.nameFr };
  } else {
    return `No session found for id ${id}`;
  }
};

// Example usage
console.log(getNameById(101)); 
console.log(getNameById(102)); 
console.log(getNameById(103)); 

However, at Line A, I’m encountering the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

What am I missing, and how can I fix this to properly retrieve the nameEn and nameFr based on the id?

the error suggests that sessions is undefined ... and if it were not undefined, it's an Object, so has no .find method anyway - once you sort out why sessions is undefined, look into Object.values or Object.entries to perform the .find

I believe this is how you can get the desired result, since the id is already a key in sessions there is no need to loop through it ( considering the id will always be used as a key as well ) you can do the following:
const sessions = {
  101: { "id": 101, "nameEn": "English 1", "nameFr": "French 1" },
  102: { "id": 102, "nameEn": "English 2", "nameFr": "French 2" },
  103: { "id": 103, "nameEn": "English 3", "nameFr": "French 3" }
}


// Function to fetch nameEn and nameFr based on id
const getNameById = (id) => {
  const session = sessions?.[id];
  if (session) {
    return { nameEn: session.nameEn, nameFr: session.nameFr };
  } else {
    return `No session found for id ${id}`;
  }
};

// Example usage
console.log(getNameById(101)); 
console.log(getNameById(102)); 
console.log(getNameById(103));
console.log(getNameById(104)); '

Output:
{ nameEn: 'English 1', nameFr: 'French 1' }
{ nameEn: 'English 2', nameFr: 'French 2' }
{ nameEn: 'English 3', nameFr: 'French 3' }
No session found for id 104


The find method doesn't exist in sessions object, you need to use the Object class and pass the sessions as argument in values method for you to use find method.


const sessions = {
  101: { "id": 101, "nameEn": "English 1", "nameFr": "French 1" },
  102: { "id": 102, "nameEn": "English 2", "nameFr": "French 2" },
  103: { "id": 103, "nameEn": "English 3", "nameFr": "French 3" }
}

const getNameById = (id) => {
  const session = Object.values(sessions).find(session => session.id === id);  // Line A
  if (session) {
    return { nameEn: session.nameEn, nameFr: session.nameFr };
  } else {
    return `No session found for id ${id}`;
  }
};

console.log(getNameById(102))




I am getting the following error message at Line A:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I think you're getting this error because you are not getting the sessions, hence being undefined or null. Can you give context as to where you are retrieving the sessions?

@flash you should consider the script.js in this playground link

Object.entries(obj).find(([key]) => key === keyToFind)
const [key, value] = foundEntry

use Object.entries to facilitate the iteration as if the object was and array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Hi to iterrate over an object in js i like the forEach method
Object.keys(sessions).forEach(function(key) {
}

Then use the key to access the values for each to get your message, i've used a random value but replace it with what ever you want
if( sessions[key]["id"] == id){
  returnMessage=sessions[key]["nameEn"]
}

So the final function can look like this
 function getNameByID(id){
      let returnMessage=`No session found for id ${id}`;
      Object.keys(sessions).forEach(function(key) {
        if( sessions[key]["id"] == id){
          returnMessage=sessions[key]["nameEn"]
        }
      })
      return returnMessage
    }
    
    console.log(getNameByID(101))

Hope this helps
